# How can I cross breed two root vegetables?

Tags: roots, hybrids

How would I go about crossbreeding two root vegetables to make a super-vegetable with properties of both? I'm thinking about crossbreeding garlic with something like turmeric/ginger to attempt to make a hardy turmeric with all the medicinal properties.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it maybe suited to botany.

Comment: Botany is a type of gardening.

Comment: a lot of scientific research... aren't there laboratories working on these?

Comment: I agree with @Graham Chiu. This is a question about hybridizing. Except for happenstance discoveries, this is not a gardening nor landscaping question.

Comment: Depends on which two root vegetables. Do they flower and crosspollinate?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. Too many root vegetables in the world. If you have a specific root vegetable (or two) you want to work with, then this might be answerable.

Comment: I was thinking garlic with turmeric, with ginger to try to breed in the desirability of all 3 for one plant.